# How to set vim PATH?

Tags: vim

The server manager told me they updated/built vim to the latest version at `/opt/vim/src/vim` but when I open `$vim`, it is still the old version. Then I check:

```
$which vim 
/usr/bin/vim
```

My question is how to set or change $PATH so that I will initiate the latest vim version?

Here is the OS information:

```
~$ uname -a
Linux ccis4301 3.13.0-88-generic #135-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 21:10:42 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I have added the info to my quieston. Also both answers I have tried but didn't work. It still come with the old version from `/sr/bin/vim`.

Answer (score 2):

In your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` set:

```
export PATH="/opt/vim/src:$PATH"
```

Comment: After I tried this, it's still the old version from `/usr/bin/vim`.

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be just `export PATH="/opt/vim/src:$PATH"`
And did you remember to `source .bashrc` after?

Answer (score 0):

`PATH` holds the lists of dirs which are searched for binaries in order one by one. Hence, the order is important.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/vim/src
```

will result in picking `/usr/bin/vim`.

We can override this by flipping the order

```
export PATH=/opt/vim/src:$PATH
```

and to make it permanent. Add this to your `rc` file like `~/.bashrc`

```
echo 'export PATH=/opt/vim/src:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```